# What the best way to store data from Javascript in "salesforce"

Tags: javascript, database

I'm writing a small analytics app in Javascript and want to store data in a database. Since I am new to salesforce I can't figure out the best way to do this:

- a normal DB such as heroku (postgresql)
- database.com (couldn't find much on how to access via JS)
- force.com ?
- APEX ?

Thanks for pointers.

Update: For now all the javscript is inside the code of the Home Page component.

Comment: If you don't have much use for CRM and would like a Postgres db, Heroku might be a better match. With salesforce you get a built in database and the Force.com platform to build apps.

Comment: @techtrekker thanks, it's a requirement to track usage of salesforce.com. Because the app needs to go into the appexchange I want to store the data as "close to salesforce" as possible, so I will look at Heroku!

Comment: The database.com API is identical to the Force.com API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally you would want to do this by sending data via a REST call to your salesforce, you can create your own REST API functions in apexrest more about that here: http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apex_rest/api_apex_rest.pdf 
In these apexrest functions you would handle the incoming data, store it in the database, do calculations, ...

The problem you have there is, you can't do cross domain rest calls, a solution here is either do the call from your webserver backend (via PHP or something else) or you include your javascript file directly from your salesforce.com domain where the rest call is being send to.

Comment: Thanks! Could you be more specific on which database to use from apex, I'm still confused whether I'd need a something like database.com or whether I can just store somewhere inside salesforce. Also regarding the cross-domain: the javascript is inside the component so on the salesforce domain, but I read that this might still be a problem. A possible solution might be this: http://iwritecrappycode.wordpress.com/2012/10/31/access-salesforce-rest-api-with-javascript/

Comment: you would create a custom object (or multiple custom objects) and use SOQL to query that data from apex, however these are the basics of Force.com, you should take a look at : http://developer.force.com/gettingstarted a good book to read is http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/Force_Platform_Fundamentals which is availble for free download over at developerforce

Comment: You can get round the cross-domain issue with a proxy - see http://blogs.developerforce.com/developer-relations/2011/04/calling-the-rest-api-from-javascript-from-anywhere.html